# Flutter: change name of named constructor argument

Tags: flutter, dart

I am creating a widget in flutter like below:

```
class CatalogWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final String errorMsg;
  final Function receiveAgainCallbackyyyyyyyyyy;
  const CatalogWidget({this.errorMsg, this.receiveAgainCallbackyyyyyyyyyy});
```

As you can see in named constructor `receiveAgainCallbackyyyyyyyyyy` is long name now my question is here?
How can i use long name argument but when i want to initialize this constructor i see short one  like this:

```
CatalogWidget(errorMsg: "test", callback: function)
```

I know this is mistake:

```
 const CatalogWidget({this.errorMsg, callback})
      : this(receiveAgainCallbackyyyyyyyyyy);
```

But i don't remember what is the correct way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

```
class CatalogWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final String errorMsg;
  final Function receiveAgainCallbackyyyyyyyyyy;
  const CatalogWidget({this.errorMsg, Function callback})
      : receiveAgainCallbackyyyyyyyyyy = callback;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```dart
const CatalogWidget({this.errorMsg, Function callback})
      : this.receiveAgainCallbackyyyyyyyyyy = callback;
```